# зачем в файле может быть написано use function + (стандартная функция php)?

Tags: php, функции

В файлах ядра pmmp много таких записей как:

```
use function fopen;
use function get_class;
use function ini_set;
use function is_array;
use function is_dir;
use function is_int;
```

Зачем они нужны если это стандартные функции php?

Comment: " это стандартные функции php"  --- да. зачем так кто-то делал только ему и известно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68699132/why-use-the-use-keyword-in-php-to-import-core-identifiers